# Hosting with OpenShift RedHat get 500 errors when access the website

Tags: laravel-5, hosting, redhat, web-hosting

I have this [website](http://freelancer-ngohungphuc.rhcloud.com/). The problem I have is

> The freelancer-ngohungphuc.rhcloud.com page isn’t working
>
> freelancer-ngohungphuc.rhcloud.com is currently unable to handle this
> request.
>
> 500

I develop this website using Laravel 5.1. So what I have to do to fix this error.

Comment: Have you given write permissions to storage directory of your project?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha I have update my source code into /app-root/runtime/repo

Comment: What I have to do to given write permissions to storage directory of my project

Comment: If you have an SSH connection to the server, go to the project directory of the project. Then do **chmod 777 -R storage/**. This will give write permissions to storage directory. If you are using a Cpanel, there must be a way to specify permissions

Comment: [Here](http://prntscr.com/atlc5v) is my current folder.I'm using filezilla to upload source code

Comment: Then right click on the storage directory, go to properties, then set permissions through that. It is better if you can use WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) over Filezilla

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha the only storage folder I see is Laravel storage folder I dont see any storage folder

Comment: Yes, storage folder in the repo/ directory

Comment: So which folder I need to upload source code

Comment: There's nothing wrong in the place where you have uploaded the source code. Just a permission issue. Set the permissions in the storage/ directory

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha thanks for your kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can usually check logs to see why you are getting a 500 error, it would appear that this is due to insufficient permissions - which need to be set on the `storage` and `bootstrap/cache` folders (as per the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1)).

The folders both need to be writeable by your web server, so whilst `777` permissions will definitely work `775` should be fine (and more secure).

Doing this via a command line can be done with the following command (run it with `sudo` if you need to elevate to root permissions) `chomd 777 -R storage bootstrap/cache` or `chomd 775 -R storage bootstrap/cache`.

Doing this via an FTP client is doable, generally speaking you can just right click on the folder and choosing to edit permissions from there.

In some instances, `vendor` may need to be done too - from my experiences anyway.

These folders are all inside the root project directory for your Laravel application.

**Edit**

Excerpt from bottom of error log:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE)

This would indicate that the PHP version you are running is not >= 5.5.9 (one of the Laravel requirements).

This is confirmed in the screenshot shown of the OpenShift configuration. The version of PHP needs to be updated for Laravel to work - this wasn't just a permission issue.

Comment: Still not working I have change permission as you told

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc are you able to look at your error log? Usually it is in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` if you are using an apache web server. This will tell you what is causing the error.

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc also when you changed the permissions, did you do this recursively to ensure they are set on all the folders inside those folders?

Comment: I only found [this](http://paste.ofcode.org/N7dsayfHY4uEdJGiKUp6AR) log file on openshift host

Comment: I'm already set the storage,vendor,bootstrap permission folder

Comment: You are getting a `class` error - it is likely the version of PHP you are running is not >= 5.5.9. You can see this by looking at the last entry. Can you check your version of PHP and update if necessary.

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc you are running PHP 5.4, you need to be running 5.5.9 or higher to use Laravel due to it using `::class` which isn't supported in lower versions of PHP.

Comment: Sorry but in openshift doesn't have version 5.5.9 for php any recommend for my issue

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc you are right, open shift only support PHP 5.4 as their highest version. You will have to look elsewhere to host your Laravel application - as OpenShift doesn't support the PHP requirement. Given that finding the right hosting provider is entirely a personal decision I would suggest you have a look around to find something you like.